# parse.com user.signup fails with error

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Below is my code to signup for a new user

```
var Account = Parse.Object.extend('Account');
account = new Account();
account.set("serviceTax", TAX.SERVICE_TAX);
account.set("educationCess", TAX.EDUCATION_CESS);
account.set("name", accountName);

var user = new Parse.User();
user.set(USER.USER_NAME, username);
user.set(USER.PASSWORD, password);
user.set(USER.EMAIL, username);
user.set(USER.FIRST_NAME, firstName);
user.set(USER.LAST_NAME, lastName);
user.set(USER.PHONE_NUMBER, phoneNumber);
user.set(USER.COMPANY_NAME, companyName);
user.set(USER.ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);

user.set(USER.ACCOUNT, account);

user.signUp(null, {
        success : function(user) {
            $('.gifload').toggle();
            bootstrap_alert.info("alert_placeholder", "User created successfully");
        },
        error : function(user, error) {
            $('.gifload').toggle();
            bootstrap_alert.error("alert_placeholder", error.message);
        }
    });
```

I am getting the following error in this signup **"user objects cannot allow writes from other users"**

Now as far i can tell, we are not updating any user, just creating one with an account object. Why am i getting this error? Any help on this will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: See if we can take the other object out of the mix.  Skip  `// user.set(USER.ACCOUNT, account);` and see if the behavior changes.  If it doesn't, then we'll know for sure its about permissions on User.

Comment: i already tried that, removed the account setting and still getting he same error.